# Boost.Build/bjam and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bjam, boost-build

I'm trying to set up a Boost.Build .jamroot file for compiling a Qt 4.8 project, but it seems to be ignoring the.ui files and the .cpp files that should be moc:ed. I tried poking around inside qt4.jam, adding some more ECHO:s, but I'm not sure where to look.

It seems that the run method of uic-generator doesn't get called (init does), for example, but I *think* it should be.

My jamroot file looks something like this:

```
import qt4 ;
if ! [ qt4.initialized ]
{
    ECHO "oh nooo" ;
}
import cast ;

exe application :
    # For example
    [ cast _ moccable-cpp : ./src/something.cpp ] 
    [ glob-tree *.ui  : .svn ] 
    ;
```

The only output I get is:

```
>bjam
warn: Unable to construct ./application
...found 1 target...
```

If I run bjam --debug-configuration, qt4.jam prints out all the correct paths for my Qt installation.

What's up? Maybe it's incompatible with Qt 4.8? Or am I just using it wrong? Although the code is almost verbatim taken from the files under examples/qt.

How can I use it?
Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Using gcc 4.7 with the MinGW distro 9.0 from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html, and the Boost.Build that comes with Boost 1.49.0.

Comment: I've seen Qt applications build with bjam Version 3.1.11 and Qt 4.7. I'd be very surprised if it were impossible with bjam Version 3.1.19 (from Boost 1.49.0) and Qt 4.8. Unfortunately, I don't really understand much of the Jam language myself.

Answer (score 1):

replace *./src/something.**cpp*** to *./src/something.**hpp***, i.e.:

```
[ cast _ moccable-cpp : ./src/something.hpp ]
```

**bjam** 's **qt**-examples tend to misunderstanding: *main.cpp* module mix up source **and** header files.

Let's remember **moc** process header files usually (files with **Q_OBJECT** 's class declaration(s): in most cases source files doesn't contain its)

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question but a suggestions: 
What about using qmake ?
It is also suitable for normal c++ builds.
If you use a lot of Qt, qmake is pretty handy,
although the documentation could be improved.

See

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2008/04/16/the-power-of-qmake/

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/qmake-manual.html

http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake

http://paulf.free.fr/undocumented_qmake.html

http://www.kde.gr.jp/~ichi/qt/qmake-manual-6.html

for further references